# How to get revision number from Mercurial server only by date?

Tags: python, mercurial

I'm not very familiar with Python & Django.
We use Jenkins as the server of Continuous Integration. But when Jenkins cloned the repository, some revisions are ommited (it's automatic process).
When we need to build a package for test/production purposes, we have to mark it with exactly the same revision number as we can check on Mercurial server (repository).
We use Fabric. 
I've tried to make a combination with Fabric & Python in one script (Python's Paramiko will be used to connect third party Mercurial server and get proper revision number).
The revision is taken from Jenkins' made package on the local server as the date of last commit. It was simple:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(
    ['hg', 'log', '-l', '1', '--template', '{date|isodatesec}', env.repo_dir],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)
```

But the problem is to take the revision number from Mercurial server. I've tried:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_conn.execute('hg log -l 1 --date /"%s to %s/" --template {rev}')
```

...but without expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Just dirty thinking:

- If you get correct dates for using in log and provide they in correct format (see `hg help dates`) (BTW, for singe log record isn't just "

  I see only small dfference with my working command and your in " chars using and escaping. JFYI, tested (on Win-side, in cmd-shell) command

`hg log -l 1 --date "Sun Oct 30 10:16:00 2011 +0600 to Sun May 27 19:55:34 2012 +0600" --template "{rev}"`

`38`

(dates was grabbed from log output "as is", maybe trailing \n in template also will play game - I'm thinking with troubles now)

**Note:**

any hg command without -R will work only if $PWD is mercurial repo. I'm afraid, any ~ isn't place of repository

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804995/how-to-use-subprocess-when-multiple-arguments-contain-spaces makes me clear. I'm messed up with this question without better searching the knowledge... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The better fix is to alter your Jenkins clone to just get everything.   You said:

> But when Jenkins cloned the repository, some revisions are ommited (it's automatic process).

Have Jenkins clone everything instead -- it only takes a long time once, and then have the jenkins logic be something like:

```
hg pull                   # get everything new
hg update XXXXXXXXXX      # update to the desired revision
./build VERSION=$(hg id)  # do a parameterized build
```

Trying to get anything except clones/pulls from a remote mercurial repository is seldom worth the complexity.