# How to use subprocess.Popen when an argument has spaces?

Tags: python, git, shell

The following command runs as expected in the shell:

```
git log --since=yesterday.midnight --before=today.midnight --format= --name-status
```

When translated into the following python code however it fails:

```
git = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'log', '--since=yesterday.midnight', '--before=today.midnight', '--format= --name-status'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Error:

```
fatal: invalid --pretty format:  --name-status
```

The closest answer I can find to this is regarding solving a problem on Windows (I'm on a Mac) here: [How to use subprocess when multiple arguments contain spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804995/how-to-use-subprocess-when-multiple-arguments-contain-spaces)

From the above answer I tried the following variations of quoting but none of them worked:

```
git = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'log', '--since=yesterday.midnight', '--before=today.midnight', '"--format= --name-status"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
fatal: ambiguous argument '"--format= --name-status"': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

git = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'log', '--since=yesterday.midnight', '--before=today.midnight', '--format=" --name-status"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
fatal: invalid --pretty format: " --name-status"

git = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'log', '--since=yesterday.midnight', '--before=today.midnight', '--format= "--name-status"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
fatal: invalid --pretty format:  "--name-status"
```

Using `""` instead of `""` in the same positions as above resulted in the exact same errors as above.

**My underlying need is to generate list of all files added and modified yesterday.**

I just learned the subprocess syntax a couple days ago so there may also be a better way to go about this. My script runs the command then calls `git.stdout.read().splitlines()` to produce a list for follow-on manipulation and partitioning of the results.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing one comma.

```
git = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "git",
        "log",
        "--since=yesterday.midnight",
        "--before=today.midnight",
        "--format=",  # <-- this one!
        "--name-status",
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately even with that verbatim I still get `fatal: invalid --pretty format:  --name-status` when the script runs. :(